# mongodb native how to work with query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm trying to retrieve data from my mongolab DB using Node-mongodb-native

```
var findAll = function () {
   var ddocs;   
   collection.find({}).each(function (arr, docs) {
    ddocs = docs;
   });
   console.log(ddocs);
};
```

But it seems that when I log ddocs, it will give me undefined, but if I log docs it will show me the data.

Please help
How should I use this function ?

Thanks 
Tzelon Machluf

Comment: Maybe you should first read the documentation and a tutorial of node.js. I'm afraid you're far away from the right solution, but you should understand it. Correcting your example doesn't make sense.

Comment: Forget the node.js part.
When I connect to mongodb and retrieve a collection. I can use the find function to retrieve data right?
Now, I don't understand how to use this data cause when I try to use it (Like the above example) ddocs = docs when docs is the data. I can undefined on the ddcos

Comment: No, node.js has a very particular programming model and node-mongodb-native is strictly aligned to it. If you don't understand node.js, forget about accessing MongoDB from JavaScript. Then you have to use another language.

Comment: OK, back to the node.js documentation.
Thank you.

Comment: Look for details about dealing with async response. The essence of this question is asked frequently in the NodeJs tags of StackOverflow, as well as MongoDb.

Comment: Thank you, for given me a direction.
I understand what I did wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

You're basically trying to create a function that will return all of the documents in a collection? If so, the below should do work. However, I agree with @hgoebl and that you should work on your understanding of node as this is not likely the best way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
var ddocs;

var findAll = collection.find().toArray( function(err, docs) {
    if(err)
        throw err;
    console.log('Collection returned');
    return ddocs = docs;
});

setTimeout( function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(ddocs);
    db.close();
}, 1000);
```

One thing in particular to note: `collection.find` is asynchronous, so the problem in your code (why it says `ddocs` is undefined) is that you're logging `ddocs` before the `collection.find` ever finished; thus, it's initialized, but no assigned any values. The Node convention is to nest callbacks so that everything happens in the right order and when it's ready.

Comment: This won't work either as this `findAll` function will return `null`; you'd need to use a callback.

Comment: @JohnnyHK You're right on that one. I just fixed it, though it looks pretty un-Node-like.

Comment: Thanks guys, I know what I did wrong and now I'm learn how to handle my problem.